# Finding expectation of joint uniform continuous distribution without integrating

Tags: probability, statistics

From SOA sample 138:

> A machine consists of two components, whose lifetimes have the joint density function
>
> $$f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> {1\over50}, & \text{for }x>0,y>0,x+y<10 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> The machine operates until both components fail.
>   Calculate the expected operational time of the machine.

I was able to get the solution by deciding on case $Y>X$, drawing a triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(0,10)$, and $(5,5)$ and then integrating $\int_0^5 \int_{x}^{10-x}{y\over50}\ dy \ dx$ to get $2.5$, and then doubling by symmetry for the case of $X>Y$ to get $5$.

However the SOA solution does it a different way that I am trying to understand:

> Suppose the component represented by the random variable $X$ fails last. This is represented by
>   the triangle with vertices at $(0, 0)$, $(10, 0)$ and $(5, 5)$. **Because the density is uniform over this
>   region, the mean value of $X$ and thus the expected operational time of the machine is 5.** By
>   symmetry, if the component represented by the random variable $Y$ fails last, the expected
>   operational time of the machine is also $5$. Thus, the unconditional expected operational time of
>   the machine must be $5$ as well.

I bolded the part that I do not understand. Where do they get $5$ just by looking at the triangle, which is $25$ in area?

Comment: Because the line from $(5,5)$ to $(5,0)$ is a [median of the triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)) and so shows the mean of the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has naught to do with the area.

The isosceles triangle, $\triangle(0,0)(10,0)(5,5)$, is *symmetrical* about the vertical line through $\overline{~(5,0)(5,5)~}$, and the density inside that shape is uniform.   Therefore the (conditional) *mean* value of $X$ given it is inside that shape is $5$.

$$\mathsf E(X\mid (X,Y){\in}\triangle(0,0)(10,0)(5,5))=5$$

Comment: So once we can make this triangle, and the density is uniform, we don't care about what the joint density specifically is, meaning it could just as well be $1\over1000$ as $1\over50$?

Comment: @abbot well, we don't need to know it's value to find the expectation.